# Rails Time Periods Beyond Midnight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I have a rails app that includes restaurants with various time periods (open and close times). For example, a restaurant may have two time periods on Monday (8am - 2pm, 3:30pm - 12am).

The problem I am having has to do with the open and close times. I am storing these open and close attributes as time types in my database and I have an instance method that checks if a restaurant is open using the current time in direct correlation with the different time periods that a restaurant may have.

The problem is when I have a restaurant that opens all the way up to midnight (12am) the restaurant is showing as closed. For example if a restaurant has a time period such as 6pm - 12am, whenever I compare this time period to the current time (Time.now > 6pm AND Time.now < 12am) it return false and thus the restaurant appears to be close even though it is not.

Has anyone encountered a scenario such as this? I was thinking about storing the duration instead, as suggested by various posts, but I could not figure out how to actually do so while compensating for the midnight and beyond times as well.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Instead of `< 12am`, how about `<= 11:59:59pm`? You calculation will be incorrect for 1 second, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Time.now.hour`

For time period such as 6pm - 12am

```
Time.now.hour >= 18
```

For (8am - 2pm, 3:30pm - 12am)

```
hour = Time.now.hour
minutes = Time.now.minutes 
(hour >=8 && hour <= 13) || ((hour == 15 && minutes >= 30) || hour > 15 )
```